# Processing Requests in the Background

Tags: asp.net, database

I'm writing a REST API using ASP.Net Core and Microsoft SQL Server. One of my requirements is that clients will `POST` certain data to this API and the API will have to transform/process the data in some way before it is used or read. Turns out this processing is costly. So I'm thinking of doing it asynchronously in the background without blocking the `POST` request. I'm considering doing the processing:

- In a scheduled SQL job
- Using a separate Windows Service running in the background that reads from the DB, does the processing and writes back to it. It'll be slower than the SQL job I presume, but the code will be more readable.
- Using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Never used it. Not sure how well it works.

What are the best options for this? Are there there any best practices around this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

## Boilerplate

- Store that data somewhere (RDBMS, nonSQL, etc)
- Respond to user that his data has been scheduled for processing
- Run some worker or pool of workers for job processing
- Store result somewhere
- Notify client that background job is complete (could be just a `GET /jobs/id` endpoint which client can check
- Show that result

You can use your own daemon, process, script. If it's not enough and you need more features use that Hangfire which is looking solid.

Answer (score 1):

I am using hangfire in production for almost 3 years, and yes this is a great way, retry policy from out of the box, UI dashboard, but extra options can be like this:

- Serverless (Azure function, AWS Lambda)
- AWS SQS or Azure Queue + Hosted services [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. I'll try out hangfire. I should've mentioned that the cloud is not an option for me. This strictly be an on-prem deployment

Comment: You can use rabbit MQ locally for example, or another pub-sub thing in your case. So the worker and producer can be separated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've found is to implement [`IHostedService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice), a built-in interface in ASP.Net Core. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice) for details.